# ActiveRecord Query with nested table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am trying to make next query with ActiveRecord and have no idea about how to achieve this SQL result without using `find_by_sql` call.

```
SELECT *
FROM table_x AS a,
    (SELECT locator, max(day_parsed) AS max_day
     FROM table_x
     WHERE day_parsed BETWEEN params[:day_from] AND params[:day_to]  
     GROUP BY locator) AS b
WHERE a.locator = b.locator
AND a.day_parsed = b.max_day
```

Any idea?

Comment: What's wrong with `find_by_sql`? Why bother converting a readable SQL query to a non-readable `ActiveRecord` code?

Comment: `find_by_sql` returns a `Hash`.  Ideally I would like to create an ActiveRecord model based in this result. I tried with a postgresql view, but because I need the date range params I discarded to use DB views. What is wrong is that I cannot use the active_record associations

Comment: For example, I would like to use an scope based in this result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, we have active record `TableX` and its table name is `table_x`, so the query will be:

```
from = params[:day_from]
to   = params[:day_to]

TableX.joins("JOIN (
                     SELECT locator, max(day_parsed) AS max_day
                     FROM table_x
                     WHERE day_parsed BETWEEN #{from} AND #{to}  
                     GROUP BY locator
                   ) as b ON b.locator = table_x.locator")
      .where("table_x.day_parsed = b.max_day")
```

Comment: what are the values of `params[:day_from]` and `params[:day_to]`?

Comment: for example "20010101" and "20160301"

Comment: If I hardcode the params  it works fine, but I am creating an scope with this query that accepts this two parameters

Comment: To ensure it works, I think you may convert `params[:day_from]` to `DateTime` first

Comment: I have edited your response with the changes I made. Thanks!